# Unable to install Appium using node.js - Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, appium, appium-android

```
C:\Users\LENOVO IDEAPAD C340>npm install appium -installer -g node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080   throw err;   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

Node.js v18.18.0 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080   throw err;   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }
```

Comment: Is `npm i --location=global appium` working?

Comment: No, not working